# lldb display invalid vector size

Tags: c++, clang, lldb

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v = {10, 20, 30};
  for (const auto e : v)
  {
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I compile like this:

```
clang++ -g -O0 main.cpp -o main.exe
```

Than I on line 7 print v with lldb. It display that vector has size 0. And I dont understand why. I've turn off all optimizations and add debug symbols.

My Steps:

1. clang++ -g -O0 main.cpp -o main.exe
2. lldb main.exe
3. b main
4. next up to line after initializing vector
5. print v

Comment: please show a [mre] as text, not images. What exact lldb command are you running?

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed my post and add repro steps.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce.  When I did `p v` after breaking at line 7, **lldb** showed `(std::vector<int>) size=3 { [0] = 10 [1] = 20 [2] = 30 }`.

Comment: You are probably doing this on Windows (guessing from the .exe)  lldb has to know the std::vector layout for the STL library you are using to be able to show the vector contents to you.  lldb uses its "data formatters" to show this info.  If you are using the Windows C++ standard libraries, lldb may not have data formatters for that library, which would explain why you don't get this printing.  You can use the lldb commands `type summary info v` and `type synthetic info v` to show the formatters.  If there aren't formatters, all lldb can show is raw contents.